# How to use jQueryUI accordion with a custom header and content div?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

I've got some divs which I want to animate like an accordion, for which obviously the most logical way of doing it is the [jQueryUI accordion](http://jqueryui.com/accordion/). But since I don't want to use the usual `<h3>` tags as headers I use [custom headers as described here](http://api.jqueryui.com/accordion/#option-header). The code I have now is as follows:

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.2/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(function(){
        $("#ticket-event-list").accordion({
            header: 'event'
        });
    });
 });
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="ticket-event-list">
        <div class="event" id="event1">First event</div>
        <div class="content">The content</div>
        <div class="event" id="event2">Second event</div>
        <div class="content">The other content</div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

This however, doesn't do anything. Since I think I'm just following the instructions and I have no errors in my console, I have no idea what I'm doing wrong here.

Does anybody know how I can get this to work? All tips are welcome!

Comment: Maybe try using CSS transitions aside from that run the CSS in JavaScript what is not working the font size? Or animation?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You are missing `.` for the class selector.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(function() {
    $("#ticket-event-list").accordion({
      header: '.event'
      //-------^ here
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<link href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<div id="ticket-event-list">
  <div class="event" id="event1">First event</div>
  <div class="content">The content</div>
  <div class="event" id="event2">Second event</div>
  <div class="content">The other content</div>
</div>
```